# Flask - Generate child choices after selecting parent

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I use `flask_sqlalchemy`, `flask_wtf`, `Jinja2` + bootstrap
and have country , city classes in `models.py`

And in template I have two dropdown one for country and another one for city,

I wanna if select A country from first selectfield , the second selectfield populate just cities for A country

and if change country the cities selectfield change cities according country selection, and also city have some areas and city selectfild and areas selectfild is related 

How Handel this case ? with keep performance good 

But in this case what is correct (`SelectField` or `QuerySelectField`) for using

(I don't know how write `routes.py` for this case)

models.py

```
class Country(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
   code = db.Column(db.String(4), unique=True)
   cities = db.relationship('City', backref='country', lazy=True)

class City(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(10))
   code = db.Column(db.String(4))
   country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'), nullable=False)
   areas = db.relationship('Area', backref='city', lazy=True)

class Area(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(20))
   code = db.Column(db.String(5))
   city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id'), nullable=False)
```

forms.py

```
address_country = SelectField('Country', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": _('Country')})
address_city = SelectField('City', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": _('City')})
address_area = SelectField('Area', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": _('Area')})
```

index.html

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label> {{ form.address_country.label }}</label>
       {{ form.address_country(class="form-control") }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label> {{ form.address_city.label }}</label>
       {{ form.address_city(class="form-control") }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label> {{ form.address_area.label }}</label>
       {{ form.address_area(class="form-control") }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX and `QuerySelectField` to return cities in the selected country.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, CSRFProtect
from wtforms.fields import SubmitField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField


app = Flask(__name__)

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = 'True'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'main.db')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '^%huYtFd90;90jjj'


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


def the_factory():
    return Country.query


def city_factory():
    return [City.query.get(item) for item in session['cities']]


class Country(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
    cities = db.relationship('City', backref='country', lazy=True)


class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'), nullable=False)
    areas = db.relationship('Area', backref='city', lazy=True)


class Area(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    code = db.Column(db.String(5))
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id'), nullable=False)


class SelectCountryForm(FlaskForm):
    all_countries = QuerySelectField(query_factory=the_factory, get_label='name', render_kw={"onclick": "cityFunction();"})
    submit = SubmitField()


class SelectCityForm(FlaskForm):
    cities = QuerySelectField(query_factory=city_factory, get_label='name')
    submit = SubmitField()


@app.route('/get-cities', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_cities():
    selected_country = request.get_json()
    selected_cities = City.query.filter_by(country_id=selected_country['selected_country']).all()
    session['cities'] = [item.id for item in selected_cities]
    return render_template('data.html', form=SelectCityForm())


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    return render_template('show.html', form=SelectCountryForm())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

show.html

```
{% from '_helper.html' import render_field with context %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="foo">
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token() }}
        {{ render_field(form.all_countries) }}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

selected-cities.html

```
{% from '_helper.html' import render_field with context %}
{% block content%}
<div id="bar">
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token() }}
        {{ render_field(form.cities) }}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

.js

```
function cityFunction() {
    var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
            }
        }
    })

    var my = $('#all_countries option:selected').val()
    var data1 = {'selected_country': my}
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-cities',
        data: JSON.stringify(data1),
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#foo').replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: after tested it , how add blank element when country changed that because when select country must click or re-select item to commit it

Comment: You select None by adding `allow_blank=True` in `cities = QuerySelectField(query_factory=city_factory, get_label='name', allow_blank=True)`